# disable "next" button if input/submit empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Below is working code, error is in comment to accepted answer**

I am trying to disable the next button if all items within a fieldset are empty. but i can only get it to disable all or none...

Walking you through the code

we make the form, separate each region by a fieldset then hide all but the first fieldset and the next buttons

When the fields are all filled out, we make the "next" button visible again

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signup-form" action="signup.php" class="text-center">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Free to join</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login" class="control-label">Your login:</label>
                <input type="text" name="login" id="login"> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-next col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-7" data-toggle="2">Next</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Just finish a few steps</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname" class="control-label">Your first name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-prev col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" data-toggle="1">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-next col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1" data-toggle="3">Next</button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>You're almost there</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dobday" class="control-label">Your birth date:</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="dobday" name="dobday" required="required">
                            <option value="">Day</option> 
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) : 
?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></option> 
<?php       
endfor;
?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="dobmonth" name="dobmonth" required="required">
                            <option value="">Month</option> 
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) : 
?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10)); ?></option> 
<?php       
endfor;
?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="dobyear" name="dobyear" required="required">
                            <option value="">Year</option> 
<?php
for ($i = (date('Y')-18); $i >= (date('Y')-100); $i--) : 
?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option> 
<?php       
endfor;
?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-prev col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" data-toggle="2">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-next col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1" data-toggle="4">Next</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>We promise not to share your personal info</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="control-label">Your e-mail address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-prev col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" data-toggle="3">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-next col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1" data-toggle="5">Next</button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Last step</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="control-label">Your password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-prev col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" data-toggle="4">Previous</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">Join Free!</button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        <div class="steps">
            <span class="active">1</span>   <span>2</span>  <span>3</span>  <span>4</span>  <span>5</span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the jQuery, my problem is with the last bit of the function

```
<script>
    $('#signup-form').ready(function()
    {
        $('fieldset').slice(1).hide();
        $('.btn-next').attr('disabled', true);

        $('.btn-next').click(function()
        {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').hide().next('fieldset').toggle('slow');

            toggleSpan( $(this).attr('data-toggle') );
        });

        $('.btn-prev').click(function()
        {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').hide().prev('fieldset').toggle('slow');

            toggleSpan( $(this).attr('data-toggle') );
        });

        function toggleSpan(toggleId)
        {
            var toggleDone = toggleId - 1;

            $('.steps > span').removeClass('active').removeClass('done');
            $('.steps > span').slice(toggleDone, toggleId).addClass('active');
            $('.steps > span').slice(0, toggleDone).addClass('done');
        }

        $('fieldset').each(function()
        {
            $(this).bind('click keyup', function()
            {
                var empty = false;

                $('input, select', this).each(function()
                {
                    if(this.name == 'email')
                    {
                        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                        if( !regex.test(this.value) )
                            empty = true;
                    }
                    if( this.value === '')
                        empty = true;
                });

                if(empty)
                    $('.btn-next', this).attr('disabled', true);
                else
                    $('.btn-next', this).attr('disabled', false);

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `this` within the click/keyup handler really refers to the fieldset. I get a feeling it is referring to `window`.

Probably you need to add an `event` parameter to the handler and use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, edited the `$('fieldset').each` function above with what fixed it....   The `this` in the `$('input, select', this)` was necessary, along with some other minor changes